# How to get controls from Form that does not use TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

in the windows form application that using TableLayoutPanel we get all control with function

```
Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls
```

is there a way to get the controls if i don't use TableLayoutPanel in my Form?

Comment: What do you mean by *get control if i don't use TableLayoutPanel in my Form* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If controls are not placed into a `TableLayoutPanel`, then they are likely to be in the main form itself. So ypu can loop through them like this:

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
  //do somthing with the controls
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method like the following:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control containerControl)
    {
        var controls = Enumerable.Empty<Control>();
        controls = controls.Concat(containerControl.Controls.Cast<Control>());
        foreach (Control control in containerControl.Controls)
        {
            controls = controls.Concat(control.GetAllControls());
        }
        return controls;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
foreach (Control c in theForm.GetAllControls())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```

Note the the method GetAllControls can be used with any `Control`, not only with `Form`